# statistics module in joomla1.5 is needed

Tags: joomla, popup, joomla1.5, visitor-statistic

I need a module to display visit statistics in details of today,yesterday,week,month and total that could be displayed as a popup window on mouse over event. My joomla version is 1.5 . is there any to do it?

thank you.

Comment: try this - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/10404 OR try this link -- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors

Answer (score 0):

We've got several dozen Joomla1.5 sites on our servers, and the most comprehensive stats we've found similar to what you're asking is at [j4age](http://www.ecomize.com/en/j4age.html) or [Joomla Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/site-analytics/11750).  It's saved the day on any number of customer conference calls.  I can't speak to how popups might work, as we've integrated it with all of our other statistics, but the data is there, and is in a good format for use with something like mootools or jQuery for popups of the data.